# Regex Python questions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Regex help.  I am searching a string and looking to find and remove text.
What I have so far is not working.

```
thisstring = "some text here
more text
findme=words15515.1515
"
a = re.compile(r'^findme=\.*')
a = a.search(thisstring)
```

I want to find and copy the entire line.

When I print a I get none.
What I am looking for help with is how do I find the line findme= and remove the entire line from the string and save the line to a variable to be used later.  As well as removing the line from the string.

Comment: First of all, your code needs triple-quoted strings. Secondly, why did you escape the dot in your regex?

Comment: `^` doesn't match arbitrary line beginnings unless you specify `MULTILINE` mode.

Comment: regex seems overcomplicated for your case. I would simply split by `'\n'` and use python's `in` operator to test for `'findme='` in each line. Also if you want multiline string literal you do need triple quotes

Comment: `for line in thisstring.split('\n'): if 'findme=' in line: dostuff()`

Comment: @bvmcode: That's a backslash.

Comment: I have the correct regex. 
a = re.compile(r'findme=(.?)*')
a = a.search(f1).group(0)

The a variable contains findme=data after
But how do I remove the line from the string, using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import re this is one way:

```
import re

thisstring = '''some text here
more text
findme=words15515.1515
'''
a = [t[0] for t in [re.findall(r'^findme=.*',r) for r in thisstring.split('\n')] if t]
```

Comment: I was getting the string from a text file that I am already using the .read().  So I do not want to loop over the string.  But that would have worked also.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex:

```
thisstring = """some text here
more text
findme=words15515.1515
"""

not_matching, matching = [], []
for line in thisstring.split("\n"):
    if line.startswith("findme="):
        matching.append(line)
    else:
        not_matching.append(line)
new_string = '\n'.join(not_matching)
```

This results in:

```
>>> new_string
'some text here\nmore text\n'
>>> matching
['findme=words15515.1515']
```

Comment: I am reading from a text file using .read().  I did not want to loop over the data.  The regex I came up with works.  But I want to know if there is a way to combine them?
I have the correct regex. 
    a = re.compile(r'findme=(.?)*') 
    a = a.search(f1).group(0) 
    removes the line from the string
    f1 = re.sub(r'findme=(.?)*', '', f1)
The a variable contains findme=data after But how do I remove the line from the string, using regex?

Comment: Why do you not want to loop over the data and why do you want to use regex?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex needs to search for a group that starts with `findme=` and the any character or number.

```
>>> a = re.compile(r'.*(findme=.*\n?)')
>>> a = a.findall(thisstring)
>>> print a
['findme=words15515.1515']
```

I suggest you to use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) if you want to find and replace string(`change_to`) from your `thistring`

```
>>> change_to =''
>>> thisstring
'some text here\nmore text\nfindme=words15515.1515'
>>> re.sub(r'findme=.*\n?',change_to,thisstring)
'some text here\nmore text\n'
```

Comment: I have the correct regex. 
    a = re.compile(r'findme=(.?)*') 
    a = a.search(f1).group(0) 
The a variable contains findme=data after But how do I remove the line from the string, using regex? Without doing a separate re.sub.  I guess is there anyway to combine both into one?  Thanks for everyone's help. 
f1 = re.sub(r'findme=(.?)*', '', f1)

Comment: `thisstring=thisstring.replace(a, change_to)` should do right?